# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returning nil

Tags: ios, icloud, entitlements

I am creating a universal ios app.  URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier seems to be working fine when testing on my iPhone, but not on my iPad - it always returns nil there. I have tried passing in both the specific entitlement and nil with the exact same results.  Both devices are running 5.0.1 and other cloud functionality is working fine on both devices.  I can see my application's data under the "Manage Storage" section of the iCloud setting on both devices as well.

```
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // Migrate datamodel
        NSDictionary *options = nil;

        // this needs to match the entitlements and provisioning profile

        NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];  // <-- comes back as nil on iPad, formatted correctly on iPhone
```

I have been working off the http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452 tutorial.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well i figured it out.  I had transitioned an old MobileMe account over to iCloud.  I still had mail from the old MobileMe account on my iPad.  The system must have been getting confused as to which account to use.  I removed the old MobileMe account on my iPad and everything is working well now.

Comment: There is a discussion of this general issue here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3393412?start=0&tstart=0